# Your Ruby version is 3.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.10

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv-gemset

I do not what to change my Ruby version to 2.6.10. I already know how to do this. What I want to do is update my Gemfile to 3.2.0

WHat are the steps to update your Gemfile to a specific version?

Comment: Edit it and update the version, and update the rbenv version? What specific issue are you having where the obvious didn’t work?

Comment: There are two places to change the ruby version in ruby on rails, first is in `Gemfile` and you have to run `bundle install` to update `Gemfile.lock`, second there is a file called `.ruby-version`, change the version there as well.

Comment: (With the caveat that Rails has nothing to do with any Ruby versioning system in play.)

Comment: I *really doubt* you're using `ruby-on-rails-3`. In fact, your question has nothing to do with `rails` (regardless of whether or not your project happens to be using `rails`). So I deleted that tag.

Comment: https://bundler.io/guides/gemfile_ruby.html